# How to make the geom_line() to be smoother in a time series plot

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am currently learning how to plot with ggplot2. 
I downloaded some COVID-19 data and I am trying to create a plot where the x axis is the date and the y is the cases.

[Data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITuF7.png)

My code is given below:

```
data<- structure(list(date = structure(c(18344, 18343, 18341, 18340, 
18339, 18338, 18337, 18336, 18333, 18331, 18330, 18329, 18328, 
18325), class = "Date"), cases = c(69L, 71L, 36L, 91L, 92L, 57L, 48L, 23L, 
252L, 75L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(1548L,1549L, 1551L, 1552L, 1553L, 1554L, 1555L, 1556L, 1559L, 1561L, 
1562L, 1563L, 1564L, 1567L))

library(ggplot2)

a<- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=date, y=cases)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line()+
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels =  "%d %b %Y") +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) 

a
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to make the line smooth (it appears as jagged from day to day), although I have tried to use the information I have seen on other posts.

I would appreciate any help :) Thanks

Comment: If you provide your dataframe in the right format, you'd get help much easily here, cause that helps people reproduce the particular scenario. Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`).

Comment: After your edit (and correcting `data = denmark` to `data = df`), the line looks perfectly straight.  You need to post data that has the problems you are describing, and you should try to make sure the code you post actually works:  the `reprex` package helps with this.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much. I am so sorry but I am completely new to this :) I have just corrected it. Hope it works :) thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `geom_smooth`?

```
a<- ggplot(data=denmark, aes(x=date, y=cases)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = "loess") +
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels =  "%d %b %Y") +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! Yes I have tried geom_smooth() without giving any additional parameters but it adds a complete random line to my plot!

Answer (score -1):

Have you cofigure the date as.Date and order the data by date before try to plot?

like this:

```
denmark <- denmark[order(denmark$date),]
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Hi, yes I did both :) Thank you!